# Should we migrate this game terminology question here?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

Subject question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/256801/whats-the-difference-between-bug-and-glitch

Should this question be migrated from Arqade to English Language & Usage, because it asks about game terminology or not? (It asks about the difference between "Bug" and "Glitch")

Answer (score 2):

Please don't. The question itself is off-topic because of the following reasons:

1. There is no research the OP has done. "What is the difference between the two words?" is not workable on English Language and Usage (ELU). The Original Poster (OP) should show us his/her own research efforts and context where s(he) heard or read the two words.

[How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):

> Have you thoroughly **searched for an answer** before asking your
>   question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
>   and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
>   the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
>   answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
>   answer!

2. We have a similar question, [Is there any word for the opposite of a “bug” in programming?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238463/is-there-any-word-for-the-opposite-of-a-bug-in-programming). We don't even know where the OP heard the two words.

ELU doesn't welcome any question without the OP's own research efforts and proper context. I think it would be better for your community to judge whether to close it or leave it open.

Comment: It was closed, and then, reopened. And, by the way, I'm the OP of it.

Comment: @John I see. Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Your question [What does “Cut the mustard” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310212/what-does-cut-the-mustard-mean) is off-topic as general reference.

Comment: Here is a Meta post on Arqade (not posted by me) related to this migration: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/should-we-migrate-this-to-english-se

Comment: @John Thanks. I posted my answer there.

Comment: In case it's not clear: we do answer "what's the difference between two words" question, so long as research is done. (see [tag:differences])